# Do someone know how to fetch post images sizes via MYSQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, wordpress

I am developing a web services using PHP with adodb classes. what I trying to do is that I need the image sizes of the post i.e(thumbnail, medium, large) size. I am able to fetch the post original image link URL from the database. But I need that post images of different sizes from the database.

Does anyone know where post image sizes are stored in the database?

MySQL query for fetching the post images is below:

```
SELECT files.meta_value AS filepath 
FROM wp_posts posts 
INNER JOIN wp_posts attachments ON posts.ID = attachments.post_parent 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta files ON attachments.ID = files.post_id 
WHERE files.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND posts.ID =$post_id
```

Comment: In the future, please tag as `wordpress` so people know.

Answer (score 1):

You can view exactly how WordPress does something by reading the source.  The function you are looking for can be found here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/media.php#L544

As other commenters said, please make sure to properly describe your question up front.

Comment: i am using ADOdb for web services for the website and only using the site database for my needs. From where wp_get_attachment_image() function returns the file size URL when we pass the sizes in the parameters?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant file size, not dimensions.  That is stored in the `wp_postmeta` table using `post_id` as the FK.  `meta_value` stores a serialized set of meta data for the attachment you are looking for.

Comment: Yes wp_postmeta table stores below **meta_key** fields 
`_edit_last` ,  `_edit_lock`,  `_thumbnail_id`,  `My custom created meta field`. `_thumbnail_id` stores the ID for the post which contains only the post original image.

what i desire is the image size URLs i.e(thumbnail, medium, large) database location.

Comment: Again, you can see exactly how WordPress does it in their source: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php#L85